# How to specify which form mode to use for a content type

Tags: 8, forms

I created a **`new_form_mode`** for a content type in **D8** and removed some fields in that form mode from **`Manage form display`** tab of the **`content type`** by selecting that **`new_form_mode`** . But how can i select that form should be displayed for that content type instead of **`default`** form mode?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike view modes you can't select form modes out of the box. To manage form modes you need a module. You can try one of these:

https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_control

https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_manager

Comment: Why didn't its not included in the core ? why they given option to only add form_modes and not managing it ?

Comment: I would choose `/form_mode_manager` module (unfortunately it does not show "`Edit as TITLE`" tab for entities created with `ECK` module, but that option is at least available in `ECK` module's "`Content list`").